# How to scrape multiple pages with Import.io

Tags: web-scraping, scrape, import.io

I am trying to scrape a a list of events from a site [http://www.cityoflondon.gov.uk/events/](http://www.cityoflondon.gov.uk/events/Pages/default.aspx), But when scrapping it with import.io I am able to extract just the first page.

How could I extract all pages at once?

Comment: I've found this course on [Udemy](https://www.udemy.com/how-to-extract-data-from-the-web) and it really helped me to understand Import.io, especially on lecture 3 where he explain more about the Crawler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can extract data with this site, with either a Crawler or using Bulk Extract. The above website uses a very simply form of pagination:

```
http://www.cityoflondon.gov.uk/events/Pages/default.aspx    
http://www.cityoflondon.gov.uk/events/Pages/default.aspx?start1=13    
http://www.cityoflondon.gov.uk/events/Pages/default.aspx?start1=49    
http://www.cityoflondon.gov.uk/events/Pages/default.aspx?start1=25    
http://www.cityoflondon.gov.uk/events/Pages/default.aspx?start1=37
```

Here is a Data Set that I created for the above URLs that should contain all the relevant information.

319aebad-88ea-4053-a649-2087011ce041

If you have further question about an individual website, please contact support@import.io

Thanks!
Meg

Comment: Happy to help! Just contact support if you need anything else in the future.